# hidden arguments with cmdargs

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

I would like to use cmdargs to pass arguments to my Haskell program. For some reasons, I would like some options to be hidden (not shown but usable) in the cmdargs help message.

Is there a way to do to that?

I'm using cmdargs 0.10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to intercept the `--help` processing and edit the
help text to remove any references to hidden options before displaying it.
Options we wish to hide can be marked with special help text (e.g. `&= help "HIDDEN OPTION"`)
and those lines can be removed from the help output.

Consider this simple main program:

```
main = cmdArgs sampleArgs >>= print
```

The path taken when `--help` is present is as follows:

```
cmdArgs = cmdArgsRun . cmdArgsMode

cmdArgs m = cmdArgsApply =<< processArgs m

cmdArgsApply :: CmdArgs a -> IO a
cmdArgsApply CmdArgs{..}
    | Just x <- cmdArgsHelp = do putStr x; exitSuccess
    | Just x <- cmdArgsVersion = ...
    | otherwise =  ...
```

To intercept help processing we can write our `main` like this:

```
main = do
  b <- processArgs (cmdArgsMode sampleArgs)
  a <- myApply b
  print a
```

where `myApply` is a version of `cmdArgsApply` which emits the edited
version of the help text.

Here is working example. The options `-s` and `--secret` will not be shown in the help text. Try it with these arguments:

```
prog
prog --help
prog --version
prog -s1234
```

Program:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, RecordWildCards #-}

 import Data.List                       (isInfixOf)
 import System.Console.CmdArgs
 import System.Console.CmdArgs.Explicit (processArgs)
 import System.Exit                     (exitSuccess)

 data MyArgs = MyArgs { file :: String, dest :: String, secret :: String }
   deriving (Show, Data)

 sample  = MyArgs { file = "input.txt"  &= help "the input file" &= opt "input"
                  , dest = "output.txt" &= help "the output file"
                  , secret = "3l33t"    &= help "HIDDEN OPTION"  &= opt "someflag" 
                  }

 main = do
   b <- processArgs (cmdArgsMode sample)
   a <- myApply b
   putStrLn $ "running program with " ++ show a

 myApply :: CmdArgs a -> IO a
 myApply b@CmdArgs{..}
   | Just x <- cmdArgsHelp = do putStr (fixupHelp x); exitSuccess
   | otherwise             = cmdArgsApply b

 fixupHelp = unlines
               . filter (not . ("HIDDEN OPTION" `isInfixOf`))
               . lines
```

Comment: This seems to mostly do the trick, except you have to be careful since the help can be laid out in multiple lines. In that case you might end up with stray lines in the output. This should really be supported by cmdargs..